# Migrating a Vaadin application to GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, vaadin, gae-eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to migrate my existing application to GAE using this tutorial:

http://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Google%20AppEngine%20HOWTO

When trying to set the application ID, I get following error message:

Cannot set application ID (appengine-web.xml is missing)

[image: Error message]

I suppose that the reason for this is that I have to set the deployment mode of the Vaadin app to "GAE".

But how can I do this for an EXISTING (not new) project?

UPD 21.08.2011, 20:14 CET:

My WAR directory (it contains appengine-web.xml):

[image: WAR directory settings]

The error I get when trying to deploy the app to GAE.

[image: Error message when deploying]

Eclipse searches for the files in "target/war" (wrong) instead of "war" (correct).

How can I fix this?

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html

Comment: I added the appengine-web.xml, then fixed some problems as explained at http://www.streamhead.com/maven-spring-vaadin-appengine/. But now I get another error - see screenshot above.